# Detect successful response from ajax function

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a function which is triggered via AJAX and will run the following when successful:

`wp_send_json_success();`

I am then doing a console log of the response and trying to detect if success = true:

```
.done(function (response) {

if( response['success'] == true ) {

    console.log('add to cart successful');

} else {
    
    console.log('add to cart failed');

}
```

Currently I am getting "add to cart failed" despite the output of response looking like it should be successful:

```
console.log(response);
```

// Response in the browser console:

```
{"success":true}
```

Am I detecting the `true` response incorrectly?

**Update** - PHP function the AJAX is triggering. Removed most code just as a test.

```
function fbpixel_add_to_cart_event_conversion_api() {

    echo 'hello world';

    wp_send_json_success();

    die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_fbpixel_add_to_cart_event_conversion_api', __NAMESPACE__.'\\fbpixel_add_to_cart_event_conversion_api');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fbpixel_add_to_cart_event_conversion_api', __NAMESPACE__.'\\fbpixel_add_to_cart_event_conversion_api');
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        action: 'fbpixel_add_to_cart_event_conversion_api',
        product_id: productId,
        variation_id: variationId,
    },
    })
    .done(function (response) {

    console.log(response);
    console.log(productId);
    console.log(variationId);
    console.log(response.success);

    if( response.success === true ) {
```

Comment: `{"success":true,"data":["hello world"]}`

Comment: Ah, got it! I should have pasted the entire code too, sorry. See the updated post and check the `dataType` under $.ajax, it was `html`, I switched to `json` and works fine. Thanks very much for the support :)

Comment: Great! So `if( response.success === true )` worked?

Comment: Yep that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use `dot notations` to check the response returned from `wp_send_json_success`, and it always works. So use it like this:

```js
if( response.success === true ) {

    console.log('add to cart successful');

} else {
    
    console.log('add to cart failed');

}
```

Give it a shot and let me know if you were able to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I should have pasted the entire code sorry. I had the wrong `dataType` set within $.ajax:

Before

```
$.ajax({
    url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
  })
```

After

```
$.ajax({
    url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
  })
```